# I am using Db2 Recovery Expert and having error with adding Managed Databases

Tags: db2, recovery, tools, db2-luw

I have Db2 11.1 installed in my windows machine and created a Linux 32 bit in my virtualbox (unfortunately my intel doesn't allow me to change the virtualization method..anyway).

I installed Recovery Expert 5.1 in this Linux box and was able to sucessfully configure my repository database (which again, resides in my windows machine). I saw 15 new connections to the repository database, all was fine. So it was the time to add a managed database. That fails with the error CTGRI0011E. Which for me doesn't make sense because I am using the same IP address, port number, user and password for when I had set my repository database.

1. The Datastore information:

[image: The datastore information]

2. The repository details:

[image: The repository details]

3. When adding the managed database:

[image: adding the database]

4. The error finally:

[image: The error I got]

If that was an error with firewall, remote access, etc...wouldn't it fail when I created my repository? It looks like a bug to me, but everytime I get back to some support, I get that things work as designed.